# Change actionbar text padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is there any way to change right padding of text in `ActionBar` ?

Here my code :

**Styles**

```
<style name="ABTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
</style>
```

**Menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:title="Test"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Android Toolbar` with `AppCompat v21` insdead of `ActionBar`.

In your main view layout put somewhere the following code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:paddingRight="@dimens/YOUR_PADDING"
    android:minHeight=”56dp”
    android:background=”@color/colorPrimary” >
    <!-- Put whatever you want here -->
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in your `Activity` or `Fragment` set `Toolbar` as `ActionBar`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

U can add menu as in `ActionBar` if U want. Set custom title and add any paddings to it (but dont forget to set no title style) or `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`.
More information [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).